# ReferenceError: $ is not defined error even though Jquery library is added before the function. why? and how to fix it?

Tags: jquery

I'm running a simple code provided by jQuery UI that is used in a simple draggable tutorial. and I get this error:

> drag.php:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous
>   function) @ drag.php:15

Why am I getting this error when I am adding the library before the function? and How do I fix it?

Screenshots of both the code and my directory where is store my libraries are attached.

[Directory for Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSH3v.png)

[Code Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrESD.png)

Comment: open console and write `$` if tells undefined then try `jQuery`

Comment: Check the paths to the JQuery includes. It might be as simple as the code not actually being present (which is normally why you see that kind of error)

Comment: Try running the function from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the path starts on **public** directory?
If you're using chrome, the network tab on DevTools will show you if the .js file has been loaded.